# how to stop custom UITableViewCell covering UITableView border lines

Tags: ios, uitableview, border

Perhaps this is a very simple answer, but I have searched everywhere and it seems everyone is trying to do the opposite of what I am trying to do. I have a custom UITableViewCell as defined below.

```
#import "TagCell.h"
#import "TagRepository.h"
#import "TagsViewController.h"
@implementation TagCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier 
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 1, self.frame.size.width, 37)];
        self.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        self.textLabel.hidden=NO;
        [self.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(self.bounds.size.width/2-40, self.bounds.origin.y+1, 300, 30)];
        self.textLabel.text= @"test";
        [self.textLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetics" size:30] ];

    }
    return self;
}
-(void) layoutSubviews
{

    NSArray *viewsToRemove = [self subviews];
    for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
        {
            [v removeFromSuperview]; //used to remove and redraw the button during a orientation change
        }
    }
   UIButton * removeButton= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    [removeButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:18] ];
    [removeButton setFrame:CGRectMake(7*self.bounds.size.width/8, self.bounds.origin.y+3, 30, 30)];
    removeButton.hidden=NO;
    [removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeTag) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [removeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(removeTag) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
    [removeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red_unselect.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [removeButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button_red_select.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [removeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_minus.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [removeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_minus.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    [self addSubview:removeButton];
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
-(void) removeTag
{
    for( int i=0 ; i< [TagRepository instance].tags.count; i++)
    {
            if([self.textLabel.text isEqualToString:[TagRepository instance].tags[i]])
            {
                [[TagRepository instance].tags removeObjectAtIndex:i] ;
            }
    }
    _reloadTable();
   // [_delegate.table reloadData];
    //RELOAD TABLE
}

@end
```

So what happens is, that when I open up the tableview when there is an active custom cell the border is not present and it appears as if there is a blank cell following it.. or something.

This is not desired I wish the cell had a border surrounding it.
The view that contains the table sets heightforcellatindex:indexpath = 40, so that delegate function returns 40 as the cell height value, I assume that the problem lies between some sort of mismatch between this and the subviews in the custom cell. Do you see anything wrong with this??

note that I have already changed the typo in Helvetica.

Comment: Set the background color of the tableview and make sure your tableviewcell has clipsToBounds enabled

Comment: Thank you, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add [super layoutSubviews] to your layoutSubviews method, the cell separators will appear. I'm not sure what you mean by the blank cell following it -- I didn't see anything like that when I tried your custom cell. Also, you should be adding (and removing) your buttons to the cell's contentView, not to the cell itself.

Comment: Thank you that did it! I don't believe I forgot the super call.